# Where is the Odoo-10's CSV binary field value gets stored in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I have created a binary field in Odoo-10 that is supposed to store CSV file on server. But when I am checking it's table at postgres instead of getting binary data in that column, I am getting something like this

```
<memory at 0x7f1539393648>
```

Where is my binary file getting stored exactly?

- my odoo-version is 10.
- I am also trying to migrate table from openerp-6 to Odoo-10, the column that stores the CSV binary has okay data at postgres table for version-6, But when I migrate that table, CSV binary column contains this **"memory at 0x7f1539393648"** again at table in version-10

Where I am making the mess. Help appreciated.

Comment: Why did you set the tag `odoo-8`? I don't see a relation here, because you're talking about Odoo 6 and 10.

Comment: I thought this binary data storing has shifted out of database into normal storage on the file system has been changed from version-8, so used odoo-8 tag.

Comment: hey that was literally quoting me :-P Okay i will let that tag stay as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Binary data storing has shifted out of database into normal storage on the filesystem around Odoo 7 or 8 as default.

You can find the files under (from odoo/odoo/tools/appdirs.py):

```
Typical user data directories are:
    Mac OS X:               ~/Library/Application Support/<AppName>
    Unix:                   ~/.local/share/<AppName>    # or in $XDG_DATA_HOME, if defined
    Win XP (not roaming):   C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data\<AppAuthor>\<AppName>
    Win XP (roaming):       C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\<AppAuthor>\<AppName>
    Win 7  (not roaming):   C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\<AppAuthor>\<AppName>
    Win 7  (roaming):       C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\<AppAuthor>\<AppName>
```

If you have set a value `data_dir` in your Odoo server config, the files can be found there.